# Model changes done in tasks not persisting

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to call a task to be completed asynchrously because it takes a long time to complete and the request will timeout if I wait for it to be completed (I'm doing some processing on an image and getting the results).  When I put prints into the task, I see it's getting executed, so I know it's not an issue with that.  When I save the model, it acts like it saved but doesn't actually permanently save it.

project > project > settings.py

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env.str('BROKER_URL', 'amqp://qisdvxct:b0iKxulu3z2evLScg1hnCNfWflDEBBm2@lion.rmq.cloudamqp.com/qisdvxct')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_celery_results',

]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

MEDIA_URL = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'accounting.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

project > project > **init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

project > project > celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'accounting.settings')

app = Celery('accounting')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

project > project > tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from quickstart.models import Receipt
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def set_something(receipt_id):
    print("doing something")
    receipt = Receipt.objects.get(id=receipt_id)

    receipt.text= "some text"
    receipt.save()
    return True
```

Looking at the logs, it seems that the field has indeed changed after calling save() in the task (even if i Receipt.objects.get it again and check the field), but if I go into the Django admin panel the changes aren't reflected there.

Why is the save not actually saving to the database?

Comment: Is this app being hosted on Heroku by any chance?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman It is hosted on Heroku!

Comment: You can't use sqlite on Heroku.

Comment: Simple solution, and explains why my past postgresql project works.  I'll try it when I get home!

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks!  I'm guessing when you say "you can't use sqlite on Heroku" you are referring particularly to using it with celery, because it seems to work by itself for the normal application.

Comment: No, you can't use it at all. Changes might seem to persist for now, but as soon as you redeploy, or scale to a second dyno, you will lose all your changes. This is because sqlite stores its data on the filesystem, which is ephemeral and local to each dyno. Celery just makes it more obvious, because it's definitely running in a separate dyno.